# Is it possible to add a post on a facebook page via the graph API without a Facebook App?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post updates automatically to my facebook page from my PHP website.
Facebook seems to force me to create an App where users can login and then post stuff.
But I don´t need all that stuff, I just want to post to the facebook page directly via code.

I went "Ok, I´ll create an App", but now for them to give my app the needed permissions, they want me to give them a login so they can test my app and stuff ... Is there no simple way to just autopost something to my own Facebook page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/#Creating ...seems pretty clear.

Comment: No, there is not. An app is the basis for almost all API usage.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your answer! And you also cannot get the permissions to post on a page without providing a login for the facebook team?

Comment: You'll need to get your app reviewed & approved, before you can use it in a "live" capacity. You can develop & test everything without that, but any posts made via your app will only be visible to users with a role in the app.